# SQLAdapter.Update does not work

Tags: c#, sql, wpf

I have a problem with SQLAdapter.Update() which doesn't work.

```
        table = new DataTable();
        mycommand = "select * from klient";
        command = new SqlCommand();
        command.CommandText = mycommand;
        command.Connection = connection;
        adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
        adapter.Fill(table);
        data.ItemsSource = table.DefaultView;
```

(data is a name of DataGrid)

when i try to update it brings effects in database but not in datagrid

```
       mycommand= "update klient set imie = 'ze'";
       command.CommandText = mycommand;
       adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
       SqlCommandBuilder builder = new SqlCommandBuilder(adapter);
       adapter.UpdateCommand = command;           
       adapter.UpdateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
       adapter.Update(table);
```

Last line is not working. Can anyone give me a hand in sorting this out?

Comment: What you mean by not working? Is it throwing any exceptions or is it just not refreshing the view of your grid?

Comment: not refreshing and it bothers me

Comment: anyone can help me out?

Answer (score 0):

```
       adapter.UpdateCommand = command;
       adapter.UpdateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
       adapter.Update(table);
       data.ItemsSource = table.DefaultView;
```

still doesn't work, i came up with couple solutions but they are not precisely with that what I wanted to acquire

```
        table.Clear();
        adapter.SelectCommand = command;
        adapter.SelectCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        adapter.Fill(table);
```

Last one is a proper way out of this problem but it's not using adapter.update()